# Why can't we calculate the atomic radii of noble gases?

Tags: computational-chemistry, atomic-radius

My book says that only the Van der Waal's radius of noble gases can be measured as these gases generally do not form compounds (except Xenon.) Then why can't we just calculate the atomic radii by computation, say solving the Schrödinger equation? Can't we make computer simulation models of isolated atoms of noble gases?

Comment: We can all right, but that's not what is called **a measurement**.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: My comment still applies. Simulation is not a measurement.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Agreed, then can't we accept the simulated model results as excatly as a measurement?

Comment: What's to accept and what for? We won't be needing those radii anytime soon. And in any case, the book says nothing about that. It just says they can't be **measured**, which is true.

Comment: @IvanNeretin What if someone asks you a question about van der Waal's radius of these gases? Also, these calculations will make noble gases fit in the trend of atomic radii across a period.

Comment: Van der Waals radii are a different thing: they can be measured. I was referring to covalent radii only. As for fitting the trend, well, yeah, I guess that kinda can be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62305/discussion-between-apoorv-potnis-and-ivan-neretin).

Comment: You can *experimentally measure* the atomic radii using x-ray crystallography. All form crystals except helium.

Comment: @porphyrin Bingo! That's exactly what I meant to say in the chat for this question.

Comment: @porphyrin  Solid helium has a hexagonal crystal structure. Also there is no such thing as an "atomic radius", that is a catch-all term for vdW radius, ionic radius, covalent radius, metallic radius. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius

Comment: @Karl, thanks, didn't know He formed a crystal.

Answer (score 4):

Covalent radius is measured as the distance ($r_\text{cov} = d/2$) between the nuclei of two bonded atoms (covalent). But, if you try to do the same for noble gases/inert gases (good luck!), as they have fully filled $np$ orbitals, they will repel each other, hence the closest distance between the two atoms is taken (high pressure, low temperature) as the van der Waals radius.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I was asking why we do not accept values produced by simulation models.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis See my remark in the chat. Your argument is invalid.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Noble gases have no covalent radius, because they do not form bonds. You cannot calculate something that does not exist.

Comment: @Karl Yes. I initially was asking for covalent radius but edited the question. See [this]{https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38808251#38808251}

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis It is pointless to compare the 95% electron propability radii of single, isolated atoms. What kind of scientific question would you want to answer with that information? You can't even prove that your calculation is correct! The values here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius#Calculated_atomic_radii are interesting from a didactic point of view, but nothing more.

Comment: @Karl Who knows when this information will be needed? Also, if they are interesting from a didactic point of view, shouldn't they be given in textbooks?

Comment: They are scientifically useless, because they do not appear in measureable reality! You cannot use those values to prove or predict anything, you cannot even prove the values themselves by some independent means. So why bother? It's unscientific. A nice mathematical excercise, didactically helpful, most likely correct, but, by all relevant criteria, unscientific. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability

Comment: You could do a calculation for a noble gas and get the radial distribution of the wave function (or derived from this the electron density). But this will be a distribution function of the radius. There is no atomic radius where the electron density suddenly stops. You could ask for characteristic points (like maximum, expectation value, where the density is below a certain threshold, where the integrated density/probability exceeds 90%, ...), but those would be arbitrary decisions.